# putting code in a dropdown menu or in a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am Wouter Sanders and I am a learning coder.

For the project I am working on, I have to create a RAL color picker which I did, but got stuck at the point where I put that code in a menu or in a button so it isn't yet on the page if you don't want it to. this is the site on wich the code is on so you can have a preview at what I am talking about : http://topverf.jtshops.nl/ralcodes.html/?___store=default# 

This is my code. Beware its a lot (I can't post all code because its to much but it's basicly all the same)
`

```
<div class="fancybox-wrap fancybox-desktop fancybox-type-inline fancybox-opened" tabindex="-1" style="width: 645px; height: auto; position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 310px; opacity: 1; overflow: visible;"><div class="fancybox-skin" style="padding: 15px; width: auto; height: auto;"><div class="fancybox-outer"><div class="fancybox-inner" style="overflow: auto; width: 615px; height: 581px;"><div id="raloption-colorpicker" style="display: block;">
        <p class="disclaimer">
           Let op! De kleuren kunnen er een beetje anders uitzien dan op het voorbeeld </p>
        <ul>
                        <li>
                                                                                                                                <div class="box" style="background-color: #d6c794; color: #000000" onclick="setRalOption('1000','D6C794','0');return false;">
                    <a href="#" style="color:inherit;">RAL1000</a>
                                        <br><span class="color">D6C794</span>
                </div>
            </li>
                        <li>
                                                                                                                                <div class="box" style="background-color: #d9ba8c; color: #000000" onclick="setRalOption('1001','D9BA8C','0');return false;">
                    <a href="#" style="color:inherit;">RAL1001</a>
                                        <br><span class="color">D9BA8C</span>
                </div>
            </li>
                        <li>
                                                                                                                                <div class="box" style="background-color: #d6b075; color: #000000" onclick="setRalOption('1002','D6B075','0');return false;">
                    <a href="#" style="color:inherit;">RAL1002</a>
                                        <br><span class="color">D6B075</span>
                </div>
            </li>
                        <li>
                                                                                                                                <div class="box" style="background-color: #fca329; color: #000000" onclick="setRalOption('1003','FCA329','0');return false;">
                    <a href="#" style="color:inherit;">RAL1003</a>
                                        <br><span class="color">FCA329</span>
                </div>
            </li>
                        <li>

    </div></div></div><a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="javascript:;"></a></div></div>`
```

Thanks in advance,
Wouter Sanders

Comment: please elaborate and  give specific problem

Comment: Could u post your code here? We can't read your mind.

Comment: My Problem is that i can't get it into a dropdown menu or make it so when i press a button a popup comes and shows thise code.

Comment: A problem would be nice

Comment: I kina posted to problem? I said this : but got stuck at the point where I put that code in a menu or in a button. That is my problem I might not have been clear enough wich is my bad sorry for that.

Comment: The problem is that the question is a bit open ended. We can not code for you but I tried give some pointers to places to look for information and continue in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really hard to determine what problem you are having so i gave it a shot. Because i think you just want to be pointed in the right direction. And because i'm having a very good day i set up a jsFiddle for you with a real basic code, so you can "fiddle" around with it for a bit, to get you started.

The fiddle is here (click on the button "colorpicker" in the result screen): http://jsfiddle.net/veritas87/EwVyS/

What i have done is, wrap the colorpicker in a "DIV" element which i set to display:none in the CSS. With a bit of jQuery i made it so when you click on the button, it toggles the slide animation on the div that wraps your colorpicker.

```
$('#showColor').on('click', function(){
      $('div.colorWrap').slideToggle(); 
    });
```

Hope this helps you!

Extra jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/veritas87/EwVyS/1/

Comment: Thank you very much this helped me out a lot. I apoligize if I wasn't clear enough in the question. I am just very new to all of this and don't know how to ask anything correctly. But I have 1 more question for you if it isn't to much trouble, so the question is that now when you press the button it opens wich is good but is it possible to make it that if you press a color it put the code from the color in a field?

Comment: No problem at all. I edited my answer with an example of how to put the clicked colors in a textfield. This is as far as i go, because i think that you -as a learning coder- should figure the rest out yourself. Swippen gave some nice tips in his answer, some places to look. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry that i keep bothering you, but I've encountered a problem once again. If i Edit it in jsfiddle everything works fine. But when i put it in notepad++ and open it in the browser the button doesn't work anymore. I know that i should find things out by myself but I have comepletely no clue what the problem can be.

Comment: You have to load the jQuery library in your HTML for it to work.

Comment: What is the quickest way to do this? Because I actualy never knew things like that where possible since nobody has ever told me to before.

Comment: This will be my last comment on this, because you really need to go and find things out yourself and how it works. (check this: http://learn.jquery.com/) 

But for now, put this: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> in the head of your code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no full code answer since it depends on other requirements or more information

But to give you an answer where you can find information, you should look at a javascript framework like jQuery/jQuery UI or such to get information on how to open a dialog and there have your color picker code.

Or look for examples of other color pickers and see how they are done.

Also remember there are many other colorpickers out there that you can use if you need a good colorpicker.

Comment: +1 on the "Also remember there are many other colorpickers out there that you can use if you need a good colorpicker"

Comment: My answer was that he should use an existing colorpicker or look for examples around the web since the full answer needs more information. I have edited the post so that I don't sound too negative.